# What is the easiest and most effective way to filter IP-only accesses?

Tags: dns, ip

On MacOS and Windows 11, I’ve repeatedly seen direct IP accesses to `*.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com` domains (discovered via PTR DNS lookups). DNS filters like NextDNS presumably don’t see this traffic at all. So what is an easy and effective way to block traffic without an associated DNS record?

Comment: Traffic goes to IP's always, DNS is just the "human name" for an IP.

so filtering based on DNS name is kinda pointless (unless you deploy deep packet sniffing and other such techniques.

however, akamai technologies is one of the big CDN companies. blocking them is probably going to cause more havoc than you think.

So why do you want to block traffic? and what makes a simple IP block not work? (as any firewall could do).

Comment: @LvB I think the ask is to be able to block access to an IP when there isn't a corresponding DNS record.  However, blocking Akamai is going to be problematic.

Comment: @schroeder that sounds to me like someone that fundamentally doesn't understand IP and DNS. but I could be wrong there.

Comment: Patrick, I think you should see now how this simply isn't a good idea. There are lots of very good reasons why a process will connect directly to an IP without performing a DNS query first, or why legitimate IPs won't be associated with domains. So, although you may *want* to do this, it simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to block all IPs that are accessed without them having been resolved from a DNS record first, and the reason is that you want to use a DNS filter as an exclusive network access control method. Is this correct?